# How can I display a imageView only once in a cell of tableView?

Tags: xcode, imageview, tableview

I'm developing a application which uses a TableView. And I'd like to add a ImageView for helping operation of user on detail view. In other words when user tap a cell in the tableview, the imageview is showed on the detail view **only once** for helping operation of user.

What should I do to implement such specifications?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could give your TableViewController a BOOL property (for example, called shouldHideHelperImage) it could initialize to NO.  When opening the detail view, you could use that property to determine whether your ImageView should be hidden or not.

```
[imageView setHidden:[<TableViewContoller name> shouldHideHelperImage]];
[<TableViewController name> setShouldHideHelperImage:YES];
```

You would have to save that value to file for persistance.  The reason I recommended  making this a property of the TableViewController rather than your detailViewController is just so that it would have to be saved and recalled less often.

I hope that helps! - though by now you've probably already solved it.